# How to use Session Management(Per Session) between my Cordova(Phonegap) Mobile App and WCF Web Service?

Tags: wcf, session, cordova

I am developing a business mobile application in Cordova. The Mobile App is communicating with the WCF Web Service. Currently I am using Ajax Request in 'Per call instance mode'(New Ajax Request for each communication). I want to use the Per Session mode. i.e a Session will be created while login to the Mobile App(First Request to the WCF). And use that session for further communications. Finally close the session at the time of logout or closing the App. Please help me on how to implement this feature?

Currently I am using the below code:

In Mobile App:

```
var url="WCF WEB SERVICE URL";    
var my_data_str="DATA To WCF IN JSON FORMAT";    
jQuery.support.cors = true;    
$.ajax({    
crossDomain : true,    
type : "POST",    
url : url,    
async : false,
data : my_data_str,     
contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",   
dataType : "json",    
success: function(result) {    
//here is the code after success communication    
},    
error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {     
var s = '' + thrownError;     
alert(s);    
}    
});
```

// I repeat the above code for all communications(like login, display data in app, enter data to save in database etc)

In WCF Web Service:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/FUNCTION_NAME")]        
public string[] FUNCTION_NAME(string[] input_from_mobile)        
{    
string[] output_from_wcf;    
// Here the code for action     
return output_from_wcf;     
}
```